# How GNU is related with Linux?

Tags: linux, gnu

I was wondering that how is Linux and GNU related to each other. Can anyone clear my doubt in it?

Thanks!

Comment: You didn't try Googling this? The first result for "Linux and GNU" is Richard Stallman [explaining the difference](http://www.gnu.org/gnu/linux-and-gnu.html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

GNU, founded by Richard Stallman, is a collection of tools which more or less help to create a fully functional operating system. GNU's goal was to create a fully free, open source replacement of UNIX.

Linux was created by Linus Torvalds with no connection to GNU. Linux functions as an operating system kernel. When Linux was created, there were many GNU components already created but GNU lacked a kernel, so Linux was used with GNU components to create a complete operating system. There is now a kernel created by the GNU team in development (GNU Hurd) which can be used instead of Linux producing a fully GNU-based operating system. However, GNU Hurd is still in development stages (and has been for 20 years) and Linux is a more mature kernel.

It is possible also (such as in the case of Android) to have a Linux-based operating system which has no GNU components.

But usually a complete operating system will consist of Linux + many GNU components, which is sometimes referred to as GNU/Linux.

Comment: Thank You for you replies.. it really helped me understand things more better!

Answer (score 2):

Originally, GNU was a project to build a complete Unix-compatible operating system piece by piece.

The plan was to rewrite each small utility according to specification, testing it on a working Unix by replacing the original one.  It went very well, except for the kernel, where progress was especially slow, probably because several good developers couldn't agree on the absolute best design.

The planned HURD kernel had in fact a very advanced design, with a lot of innovations, but it seemed that it wouldn't be completed any time soon.

Meanwhile, Linus Torvalds was writing his own kernel, mainly to teach himself how to control low-level aspects of the Intel 80386 processor.  At first it was just a task switcher, but he quickly implemented most of the old syscalls specifications, until he managed to run most of MINIX (another Unix-like system, mostly used in education) environment on top of the new kernel.

Soon, other people suggested using GNU utilities instead of MINIX ones, and got a much more complete system.  It worked so well that most GNU developers just adopted the Linux kernel instead of perpetually waiting for the HURD kernel.

The resultant OS is commonly called just "Linux", but it's true that Linux is just the kernel.  All the GNU utilities are a lot more lines of code, so it would be more properly be called GNU/Linux.

Comment: Thank You for you replies.. it really helped me understand things more better!